# How to accept a Retrofit response if I don't know the key?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, rx-java

So, I have an API that dependent on the path will return a JSON array for that month, usually formatted like this:

```
{
   "January": []
}
```

I want to write a Retrofit call (also using RxJava, but irrelevant I think), but since I could have January, February, etc... I don't know what class to write. I could hack something like this:

```
public class JanuaryEvents {
    public List<Events> January;
}
```

And in my service do this:

```
@GET("{year}/{month}.json")
Call<JanuaryEvents> getEvents(@Path("year") String year,
                                          @Path("month") String month);
```

But obviously, that won't work for all months without creating twelve different calls which seems obnoxious and there has to be a better way.

What can I do?

EDIT: I just found out that if I do `Call<Object>` it assigns it to a LinkedTreeMap, which I could probably work with. Do you think that's the way to go? I could accept a `Call<LinkedTreeMap>` and get the items from the first node.

Comment: Look who is here huh? Can't you reverse-engineer this? Like print out the json Log then you will know the key?

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes, but the key is not consistent. So I think I might have to change it to accept a LinkedTreeMap or an Object and change it myself.

Comment: Okay, that could work I believe

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Response<JsonElement>`:

```
@GET("{year}/{month}.json")
Call<JsonElement> getEvents(@Path("year") String year, @Path("month") String month);
```

Response:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                //do whatever you want with Json Object. Deserialize it, get values by keys, get as String etc.
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(response.message());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The best I've come up with so far is to use a `LinkedTreeMap` which is part of the gsonconverter I use with retrofit.

The service looks like this:

```
@GET("{year}/{month}.json")
Call<LinkedTreeMap<String, List<Event>>> getEvents(@Path("year") String year,
                                                           @Path("month") String month);
```

And I receive it like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<LinkedTreeMap<String, List<Event>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LinkedTreeMap<String, List<Event>>> call, Response<LinkedTreeMap<String, List<Event>>> response) {
                if(response.body().size() == 1) {
                    for(String key : response.body().keySet()) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Num events: " + response.body().get(key).size());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LinkedTreeMap<String, List<Event>>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```